# How do I do this "join"?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, workbench

We have created a vocabulary with terms this way:

```
(main term A)
  |
  +-- subterm A1
  +-- subterm A2
  +-- ..
  \-- subterm A3

(main term B)
  |
  +-- subterm B1
  +-- subterm B2
  +-- ..
  \-- subterm B3
```

Easy right?

Then we've created "`main terms`" roles. Then we've used the [taxonomy_access](http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_access) for those "`main terms`" roles. I.e. The rôle called `main term A` will only be allowed to create subterms of the `main term A` term.

Easy right?

Now we need reviewers. So we've "split" "`main terms`" roles in two:

- "`main terms A contributors`"
- "`main terms A reviewers`"
- "`main terms B contributors`"
- "`main terms B reviewers`"
- ...

And we've used the [workbench](http://drupal.org/project/workbench) module to give rights to contribute / or / review. The problem is that the rights given are not detailed enough: if you give "`main terms reviewers`" the right to "review", he/she is allowed to review **all** the "needs-review" nodes. Example: "main terms A reviewers" have the "review" right, so (like it is now) they have the right to review **all** "needs-review" nodes. We'd like them only to see/review *only* the nodes based on their roles: "main terms A reviewers" should only be allowed to review "main terms A needs-review" nodes. We could have used the [workbench_access](http://drupal.org/project/workbench_access) but this would implie create a section for each "`main terms`". This would kind of force us to duplicate all our "`main terms`" into "`sections`" then give "`sections`" right.

How would you do?

Maybe there's another possibility: the workbench tab is a view. So maybe it could be possible to add a filter based on the taxonomy access control, but it seems that taxonomy access control has no api, and we should have to create a manual join. Maybe there's a way to create a fully customized join based on the taxonomy access control? If so, may I ask how you would do this?

If you think I'm not on the right track, don't hesitate to give me your solution!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest option is leave everything as you have it in terms of configuration and your taxonomy term values for `main terms`. The default Workbench (Moderation) logic isn't nested enough for you. So use it's supported hooks to extend the functionality to meet your needs.

Look at [hook_workbench_moderation_access_filter()](http://drupalcode.org/project/workbench_moderation.git/blob/6bdb20e6f88f0a4bd564309d680bc367e311a6e2:/workbench_moderation.api.php#l19)

```
/**
 * Allows modules to alter moderation access.
 *
 * @param &$access
 *   A boolean access declaration. Passed by reference.
 * @param $op
 *   The operation being performed. May be 'view', 'update', 'delete',
 *   'view revisions' or 'moderate'.
 * @param $node
 *   The node being acted upon.
 */
function hook_workbench_moderation_access_alter(&$access, $op, $node) {
  global $user;
  // If the node is marked private, only let its owner moderate it.
  if (empty($node->private) || $op != 'moderate') {
    return;
  }
  if ($user->uid != $node->uid) {
    $access = FALSE;
  }
}
```

By implementing this hook for the node access check, you can define the nested taxonomy check you're wishing Workbench_Moderation did for you. In order to find if some node has a value of a certain parent term you may find the [Taxonomy Edge API](http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_edge) module useful. Then again you might not need Taxonomy Edge.

I believe the Views workbench uses will also support this runtime check.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, it's what i was looking for.